# Filter WooCommerce related products by Polylang language

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm using [polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) plugin to having multi-languages website.

Using WooCommerce with polylang demands duplicating each product for each language, so assuming I have Hebrew and English, that means 2 duplications for each products.

It works fine with WooCommerce plugin, but when I'm displaying "related products" at the end of the product page, it's mixing products in English and Hebrew together.

I expect to filter the related product by website current language (`if(get_locale() == 'en_US')` - to check website current locale state, else will represent Hebrew).

[Polylang functions](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/)

Here is what I have tried, but I got stuck on the part of filtering the product by language:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts', 'custom_related_products' );
function custom_related_products($product){
    global $woocommerce;
    // Meta query
    $meta_query = array();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->visibility_meta_query();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();
    $meta_query   = array_filter( $meta_query );
    // Get the posts
    $related_posts = get_posts( array(
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => '4',
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'fields'         => 'ids',
            'meta_query'     => $meta_query
        ) );

        if ( $related_posts->have_posts() ) {
          while ( $related_posts->have_posts() ) : $related_posts->the_post();
            if(pll_get_post_language(get_the_ID())){
               //Not sure its the right approach for this..
            }
          endwhile;
        }
    $related_posts = array_diff( $related_posts, array( $product->id ), $product->get_upsells() );
    return $related_posts;
}
```

How can I filter Woocommerce related product section by language?

Edit

So after a little bit of research and help in the comments I found out that `'lang' => 'en'`  argument does exist, but even when I use it, there is no change on related products language display.
Any ideas?

Comment: Not working with WP on regular basis but you should make distinction in that array inside `get_posts` function. I assume those key/values are something like WHERE for SQL so you should check how to add that selection (i.e. pseudocode: `lang => 'en'`). This is just example where I would try, not that I am using WP or polylang.

Comment: @Tpojka I have tried that, doesn't gives me any error but neither result :\ Do you have any other ideas what to do?

Comment: Try 'suppress_filters' => false, arg in your get_posts() function

Comment: @mujuonly Thank you! you solved it, can you write answer please that explain what suppress_filters does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts', 'custom_related_products' );
function custom_related_products($product){
    global $woocommerce;
    // Meta query
    $meta_query = array();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->visibility_meta_query();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();
    $meta_query   = array_filter( $meta_query );
    // Get the posts
    $related_posts = get_posts( array(
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => '4',
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'fields'         => 'ids',
            'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
            'suppress_filters' => false
        ) );

        if ( $related_posts->have_posts() ) {
          while ( $related_posts->have_posts() ) : $related_posts->the_post();
            if(pll_get_post_language(get_the_ID())){
               //Not sure its the right approach for this..
            }
          endwhile;
        }
    $related_posts = array_diff( $related_posts, array( $product->id ), $product->get_upsells() );
    return $related_posts;
}
```

`suppress_filters` There is a way to make get_posts cache the results however, the suppress_filters option is true by default, but if you set it to false, the caching mechanisms inside WordPress will do their work, and results will be saved for later.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$related_posts = get_posts( array(
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
    'lang'           => 'en'
) );

if ($related_posts) {
    foreach ($related_posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        // something like <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

This code correctly returns code in selected language on my site

Comment: Hey Pavel, this is my link to my site: https://nouvellemaison.co.il/en/product/example-english/   As you can see it doesn't work, I think the hook might be out dated? because nothing has changed...

Comment: I see parameter suppress_filters helps you to solve the problem. You can combinate it with my code to get perfect query)

Answer (score 1):

While working on a custom WordPress REST Api end point to fetch post by selected language or device language, this worked. See if it can help you out.

```
function mycustomplugin_posts($params) {
    // get the url params

    $page = $params->get_param('page') ? $params->get_param('page') : 0;
    $per_page = $params->get_param('per_page') ? $params->get_param('per_page') : 10;
    $offset = $params->get_param('offset') ? $params->get_param('offset') : 0;
    $order = $params->get_param('order') ? $params->get_param('order') : 'desc';
    $order_by = $params->get_param('order_by') ? $params->get_param('order_by') : 'date';
    $lang = array_search($params->get_param('lang'),polylang_json_api_languages(), true) ? $params->get_param('lang') : pll_default_language();
    
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'page' => $page,
        'numberposts' => $per_page,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'order' => $order,
        'orderby' => $order_by,
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy'  => 'language',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => $lang
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $posts = get_posts($args);
    $data = [];
    $i = 0;

    foreach($posts as $post) {
        
        // Extract the post data

        $data[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
        $data[$i]['title'] = $post->post_title;
        $data[$i]['content'] = $post->post_content;
        $data[$i]['excerpt'] = e42_the_short_content($post->post_content, 300);
        $data[$i]['slug'] = $post->post_name;
        $data[$i]['date'] = $post->post_date;
        $data[$i]['link'] = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $data[$i]['author'] = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author);
        $data[$i]['categories'] = array();
        $data[$i]['featured_image']['thumbnail'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'thumbnail');
        $data[$i]['featured_image']['medium'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'medium');
        $data[$i]['featured_image']['large'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'large');
        
        foreach(get_the_category($post->ID) as $category){
            array_push($data[$i]['categories'],$category->term_id);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    
    // Create the response object

    $response = new WP_REST_Response( $data );

    // Add a custom status code

    $response->set_status( 200 );
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php
Move this to child theme
yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php

And add the following line to the foreach loop

```
if (pll_current_language()!=pll_get_post_language($post_object->ID)) {
    continue;
}
```

Basically if current language does not match product language we skip over it.